# use the service container in FOS doctrineFIxture

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures

I'm using the [DoctrineFixtureBundle](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle) to manage my fixture in my web app and I would like to used default images to initialize medias.

To do so I need to access the service container to get the `RootDir` parameter. Here are my fixtures :

```php
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $root = new User();

        //init user parameters

        $image = new Image();
        $image->setImageFile(fopen($this->container->getRootDir().'public/image/default/no-profile-pic/jpg', 'r'));
        $root->setProfilePic($image);

        $manager->persist($root);
    }
}
```

I followed this [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#accessing-services-from-the-fixtures) but it return me the following error :

```
 Notice: Undefined property: App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures::$container
```

Am I stupid or is the AppFixture class is not aware of the container ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing the full container is not the solution anymore. You need to use DI instead by changing your class definition as for your password encoder